# Is there a name for wrong order coding

Tags: python, error-handling

My title might be a bit vague but my question is if there is a name for this.

```
print("data has been written to the database")
db.write(data)
```

So here the confirmation message was sent first but only then the operation was carried out. So if the database write fails the user would still think that it would have been succesfull. Is there a name for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll call that **unhandled response**, because the message you're displaying should correspond to the response of your `db.write(data)`.

Btw, a proper way to fix that is to use the try-except structure. It'll give you something like that:

```
try:

    db.write(data)
    print("data has been written to the database")

except error:

    print("data hasn't been written to the database")
    print(error)
```